# What are all the exceptions that boost numeric_cast can throw?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, casting

My program (mainly in cpp) uses [`boost::numeric_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html#boost_numericconversion.improved_numeric_cast__.introduction) to ensure safe type conversions. I need to add a wrapper around it to print out additional specific details about the exception thrown by the numeric_cast to be more useful to debug my program.

I looked for the `numeric_cast` and the exceptions thrown by it to make full use of it and log additional details specific to the exception encountered. I observed that it has a `bad_numeric_cast` exception and it includes the `negative_overflow` and the `positive_overflow` exceptions as well. Are there other exceptions covered by the numeric_cast as well?

I'm new to programming, maybe searching this might be handy for you people. Please suggest so I can follow it for searching/exploring other stuffs in the future as well...

**UPDATE:**

The websites I went through:

- [boost.org](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html)
- [oreilly.com](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch03s07.html#cplusplusckbk-CHP-3-SECT-6.4)
- [theboostcpplibraries.com](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.numeric_conversion)

Comment: The documentation you use is for a very old version of Boost. These days there's no stand-alone "Boost numeric_cast" library, instead there's only a [Boost MPL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) version of [`numeric_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/numeric-cast.html). There's also the rather new general-purpose [convert](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/convert/doc/html/index.html) library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, is the `boost-mpl` `numeric_cast` has a detailed documentation with some examples? I think I'm bad at searching...